# Use Apple Script to open Chrome with specific profile

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I use multiple instances of the Chrome browser for different profiles, each with their own google account. I'm trying to automate a task using Applescript and Automator, and have set up Automator to feed a set of URLs to chrome, then run the following script:

```
    # input is the list of url's from the previous task
on run {input, parameters}

    # The below is an applescript loop
    repeat with theURL in input
        tell application "Google Chrome" to open location theURL
    end repeat

    # We must return something so we just return the input
    return input

end run
```

Is there away to specify that I want to open Chrome with the browser version I specify in the "Person" or profile of Chrome, i.e. as user XXXX@gmail.com and not as user ZZZZ@gmail.com?

Comment: RE: "# We must return something so we just return the input" -- Unless there is an explicit reason, i.e. the next _action_ in the _workflow_ needs _input_ from this _action_, then there is no requirement, programatic or otherwise, to return anything! `return input` is just part of the _template code_ provided by the **Run AppleScript** _action_ for convenience.  It can and should be deleted if it's not specifically needed by the next _action_ in the _workflow_, or this is the last _action_ in the _workflow_.

Comment: How do you have multiple instances of **Google Chrome** open? When I try to open another occurrence, e.g. from **Terminal** with `open -n -a 'Google Chrome'` it just terminates and opens another _window_ for the previous occurrence.

Comment: @user3439894 That's exactly the issue. I don't know how to programatically indicate an alternate profile - either on command line or in AppleScript. I can open alternative profile versions in Chrome itself by clicking the profile image next to the three dots upper right and choosing one of the "other people" I've added.

Comment: When you said "I use multiple instances of the Chrome browser for different profiles" I interpret that as, if I run `pgrep -n Google\ Chrome` in **Terminal** I will be back multiple **PID**s, is that the case? Or, are you just getting a new _window_ that's accessing a different **profile**?

Comment: One PID, multiple windows accessing different profiles.

Comment: Okay, so you do not have multiple instances, you have one instance with multiple windows, any of which may be using a different profile. The **AppleScript** _dictionary_ for **Google Chrome** does not have any direct method to open a new window to a given profile. That said, there is a way to programmatically open a new window to a given profile, is this what you're looking for? It involves **UI Scripting**, which really should only be used if there isn't a reliable alternative.

Comment: Actually, there is a way you can directly open to a given profile using the _command line_, e.g. `open -na "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory=Default` and for a different _profile_ change `Default` to e.g. `Profile 1`, and so on, and this is the name of the _profile folder_ in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` not your name.

Comment: @user3439894 That WORKS on the command line. I'll try porting it to Applescript tomorrow. But if you want to write that up as an answer I'll accept it. Awesome sleuthing, THANKS.

Comment: BTW Here is where I found `--profile-directory`: [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to open multiple *windows* in **Google Chrome** with each set to a different *profile* and open a bunch of tabs in each one, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* demonstrates the concept:

```
set myURLs to {"https://www.google.com", ¬
    "https://www.news.google.com", ¬
    "https://apple.stackexchange.com"}

set myProfiles to {"Default", "Profile 1"}

repeat with aProfile in myProfiles
    do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory=" & aProfile's quoted form
    delay 1
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        tell front window
            set URL of active tab to first item of myURLs
            delay 0.5
            repeat with i from 2 to count of myURLs
                make new tab at after (get active tab) with properties {URL:item i of myURLs}
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            set active tab index to 1
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 1
end repeat
```

- **Note:** The *value* for `--profile-directory=` is that of the *name* of the *folders* in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` that corresponds to each *profile*, not your name.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>