# Automator: Applescript - Open a specific Google Chrome profile and use extension

Tags: applescript, automator, google-chrome

I've been messing around but can't figure this out. Is it even possible?

I want to automate a task where it will:

1. Open a specific Google Chrome profile.
2. Run a specific command from an extension.

---

I tried playing around with this script

```
set myURLs to {"https://www.google.com", ¬
"https://www.news.google.com", ¬
"https://apple.stackexchange.com"}

set myProfiles to {"Default", "Profile 1"}

repeat with aProfile in myProfiles
do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory=" & aProfile's quoted form
delay 1
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell front window
        set URL of active tab to first item of myURLs
        delay 0.5
        repeat with i from 2 to count of myURLs
            make new tab at after (get active tab) with properties {URL:item i of myURLs}
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        set active tab index to 1
    end tell
end tell
delay 1
end repeat
```

I can't seem to find a way though to make it just open a chrome profile.

any tips?

thank you

====

Update:

Anyone? I've been trying with this script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
delay 0.3
end tell        
tell application "System Events"   
tell process "Google Chrome"
    tell group "Extensions"
        tell button "Layout Manager"
            --click
            perform action "A"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

It gives me a script error (System Events got an error: Can’t get group "Extensions" of process "Google Chrome".)

"Layout Manager" is the extension name and "A" is the action I want to enable.

thanks

===

Still messing around but I can't even open the specific profile.
I used:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Google Chrome"
    click menu item "Profile" of menu 1 of menu bar item "People" of menu bar 1
end tell
open location "http://example.com"
open location "http://anotherexample.com"
end tell
```

But it gives me:
"System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar item "People" of menu bar 1 of process "Google Chrome"."

Anyone?

===

Edit:

So I managed to run the Chrome profile. Still trying to run the extension function.

Extension name: Multi Layout Manager

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-layout-manager/ijpiffheldgmdkbaohoilabdnmeinand?hl=en

With it you can save various browser setups (tabs, position, size) and apply them whenever you want.
I want the script to click on the extension and then click on a setup (Setup A, Setup B, etc.)
The extension is pinned.

I'm trying out this code I found but my knowledge is limited

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
delay 0.3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "Google Chrome"
    tell group "Extensions"
        tell button "Multi Layout Manager"
            click
            --perform action "Setup A"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

I get the following error message:
"System Events got an error: Can’t get group "Extensions" of process "Google Chrome"."

It seems to me that I can't show it which button to click.

I'm still running HS (10.13.6) and Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (x86_64)

PS: When you respond, do I edit the main question or post an answer? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Please add the script you currently have.

Comment: Please see the **Update to address Multi Layout Manager extension** _section_ in my answer.

Comment: I did and it works! thanks! You said this way of scripting is prone to failure. Is there anything basic I should try to avoid doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is not meant to answer everything asked in your question and is just to give you some guidance on the items mentioned herein.

The first *block* of *code* in your question comes from my answer [A: Use Apple Script to open Chrome with specific profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389529/use-apple-script-to-open-chrome-with-specific-profile/389891?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.0479#389891) and it does indeed do exactly what it is programed to do, assuming there are two profiles.

You should have a look at my answer [A: Create a terminal command to open another user profile in chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401223/create-a-terminal-command-to-open-another-user-profile-in-chrome/401227#401227) as it shows the basic *command* to open **Google Chrome** to a specific profile. That *command* is also used in the `do shell script` *command* in the *code* of the other answer, the code you show in the question.

So, to open **Google Chrome** to a specific *profile* the *code* is there, right in front of you:

```applescript
do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory=" & aProfile's quoted form
```

Where `aProfile's quoted form` is in the *list* `{"Default", "Profile 1"}`, so to just target one *profile*, e.g.,:

```applescript
set myProfile to "Profile 1"
do shell script "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory=" & myProfile's quoted form
```

As to some of your other *code* attempts, here is an example of how I'd click a *menu item* from the **Profiles** *menu* in **Google Chrome**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

delay 0.25

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click ¬
        menu item "Edit…" of ¬
        menu "Profiles" of ¬
        menu bar item "Profiles" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Google Chrome"
```

In the *example* **AppleScript** *code* you'd replace `"Edit…` with then the *name* of the *profile* you want, as it shows on the **Profiles** *menu*.

To bring up the **Extensions** is would be:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

delay 0.25

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click ¬
        menu item "Extensions" of ¬
        menu "Window" of ¬
        menu bar item "Window" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Google Chrome"
```

---

Not trying to overwhelm you, however, if you need to click several first level *menu items* in the same *script*, it's probably better to implement it as a *handler*, e.g,:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
my clickApplicationMenuCommand("Google Chrome", "Profiles", "Edit…")

my clickApplicationMenuCommand("Google Chrome", "Window", "Extensions")


--  ## Handler ##

to clickApplicationMenuCommand(appName, appMenuName, appMenuCommand)
    tell application appName to activate
    delay 0.25
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        click menu item appMenuCommand of ¬
            menu appMenuName of menu bar item appMenuName of ¬
            menu bar 1 of application process appName
end clickApplicationMenuCommand
```

You would place the *handler* at the bottom of your *script* and then just click a top level *menu item* as shown in the two examples of calling the *handler*.

---

### Update to address **Multi Layout Manager** *extension*

The information above was tested in **macOS Catalina** as it was not know at the time what version of **macOS** the OP was using.

This update to address triggering a **Layout** of the **Multi Layout Manager** *extension* in **Google Chrome** when the *extension* itself is *pinned* to the **Toolbar**.

Having installed the **Multi Layout Manager** *extension* in **Google Chrome** under **macOS High Sierra** and ascertaining the **UI element** *hierarchical object structure* to e.g. **Setup A** and upon closer examination of it, I was not able to get past a certain point in it.  As such I decided to stop wasting time and revert to the an ugly form of **UI Scripting**.

Note that **UI Scripting** is often *kludgy* and prone to failure for a number of different reasons, which I'm not going to enumerate here.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes **Google Chrome** is already running and the wanted **Profile** is active.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

delay 0.25

tell application "System Events"
    click ¬
        pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of ¬
        toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 of ¬
        application process "Chrome"
    
    delay 0.25
    
    repeat 3 times
        key code 48 -- # tab key
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    key code 36 -- # enter key
    
end tell
```

**Notes:**

As coded with the `repeat` *loop*, it triggered the first **Layout**, so to trigger the second **Layout** the `repeat` *loop* would need to be incremented by `1`, and so on.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! I played around and it managed to make it open the profile that I wanted.

I'm struggling to make it run the extension command though. I used your script and it opens the extension tab.
What I want is to click on a specific extension (next to the url bar) and then run a function of it. 
It seems to be this is a matter of "clicking" the right buttons. Is there a way to check what's what? Like road-mapping the buttons?

thanks

Comment: My knowledge is limited so I'm walking in the dark here but I'm trying to make it work  using this script:

    tell application "System Events"
 tell application process "Google Chrome"
  set frontmost to true
  tell (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow")
   tell toolbar 1
    tell (first button whose accessibility description is "Multi Layout Manager")
     perform action "AXPress"
    end tell
   end tell
  end tell
 end tell
    end tell

It won't though, my understanding is that I can't show it which button/functions I want it to find.

Comment: @KhalDrogoSings, This site works so much better with one question per question and it's not unusual to grt a quest closed when asking more that one question or get the extra question(s) edited out. That said, either post a new question regarding this one item or edit your question adding the details. That being the _code_ you tried and results/error message. Also please provide explicit and specific details of the _extension_, its _name_ or better the **URL** so I can download it. Whether or not its _pinned_ and what _command_ or _menu item_ or **UI element** you are trying to click.

Comment: @KhalDrogoSings, Also, What version of **macOS** are you running and what version of **Google Chrome**?

Comment: apologies, I wasn't sure you'll see my response if I edited so I left a comment, new here. I now edited the main question. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, this worked like a charm! thanks!
You said this way of scripting is prone to failure. Is there anything basic I should try to avoid doing?