# Scroll down - change scrollbar position using AppleScript (combined with another script)

Tags: applescript, automator, google-chrome

So a great guy helped me ([Automator: Applescript - Open a specific Google Chrome profile and use extension](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425929/automator-applescript-open-a-specific-google-chrome-profile-and-use-extension)).
Now, I want to implement the next step into this.

I can now run a specific Chrome profile and use a specific extension function that basically opens a Chrome setup that I saved (various websites opening with specific dimensions on my monitors and with specific placements)

This is the script:

```applescript
set chrome to "\"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome\""
do shell script chrome & " --profile-directory=\"Profile 6\"" & " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
delay 0.25
tell application "System Events"
    click ¬
        pop up button "Multi Layout Manager" of ¬
        toolbar 1 of group 1 of window 1 of ¬
        application process "Chrome"
    delay 0.25
    repeat 3 times
        key code 48 -- # tab key
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    key code 36 -- # enter key
end tell
```

What I want now, is for some of these websites to change their scrollbars so that I can see the part of the website that interests me in front of me.

I've found this script that works but only by itself.

```applescript
set myURL to "https://weather.com/weather/hourbyhour/l/12345"
set scrollAmount to "16" --- % down the page

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell front window to set curTab to make new tab at after (get active tab) with properties {URL:myURL}
    tell curTab
        repeat while (loading)
            delay 1
        end repeat
        -- set the vertical scroll 
        execute javascript "h=document.documentElement.scrollHeight- 
    document.documentElement.clientHeight; window.scrollTo(0,h*" & scrollAmount & "/100)"
    end tell
end tell
```

I tried, but my knowledge is limited and can't make the two of them work together.

On its simple form, I want the script to pick one of the sites that the first script opens and change its scrollbar.

Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I managed to make it work using this script:

```applescript
delay 3
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
    execute javascript "window.scroll(0,270)"
end tell
```

The issue now is that it takes the active tab and applies the scroll function. I want it to find a different tab and apply it.

The tab is in a different window though.

Any way around it?

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit as it answers your question and that is not how things are done here. You can self-answer your question by posting an answer of how you resolved your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was pretty simple. I just had to put window 2.

```
delay 3
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 2
    execute javascript "window.scroll(0,270)"
end tell
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a Safari url in a new tab rather than in a new window you can do

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"$1"})
    end tell
end tell
```

If you want to switch to a tab with a specific url

```
    tell application "Safari"
    set desired_tab to null
    set tablist to every tab of window 1
    repeat with t in tablist
        if URL of t is "https://www.google.com/" then
            set desired_tab to t
        end if
    end repeat
    
    if desired_tab is not equal to null then
        set current tab of window 1 to desired_tab
    end if
end tell
```

Be careful though the url here needs to be an exact match

Get it in the javascript console if you need to with

```
window.location.href
```

This example shows selecting a
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242098/applescript-find-open-tab-in-safari-by-name-and-open-it][safari tab by name in applescript]

Comment: thank you! I managed to make it work but this could be useful for a future reference.